# How can I export external content type as a BDCM file with powershell?

Tags: 2010, development, sharepoint-designer, powershell

I can export external content type from SharePoint Designer or Central Administration. However, I want to export ect as bdcm file with powershell in order to export ect automatically.

There is an exapmle in techNet Export-SPBusinessDataCatalogModel;

```
  $Model = Get-SPBusinessDataCatalogMetadataObject -BdcObjectType "Model" - Name "ContosoModel"  -ServiceContext http://contoso  
  Export-SPBusinessDataCatalogModel -Identity $Model -Path "C:\folder\model.bdcm"
```

File was created with this command but the file content is not similar with SP Designer export file.

How can I do that.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this in the past with success for a full catalog

```
$mybcsMeta = Get-SPBusinessDataCatalogMetadataObject –ServiceContext http://sp.local –BDCObjectType Catalog –Name MyModel
Export-SPBusinessDataCatalogModel –Identity $mybcsMeta –Path C:\BCS_Model.bdcm
```

The differences could come from the use of the parameters which have different defaults via UI(SPD or SPCA vs Powershell).

- ModelsIncluded  —Models are included in the exported XML file
- PermissionsIncluded  —The permissions to the model are included in
  the export
- PropertiesIncluded  —Specifies that BCS properties are    included in
  the export

Comment: If I am wrong, please correct me! Your suggestion is not a different solution from my script. I don't understand that why we set the parameters instead of using values directly. I think no difference!!

Comment: You are right, thank you, while executing the command I've made a copy/paste, see updated answer please!

Comment: I am looking on exporting bdcm file with powershell or c#, I couldn't find specific example or information about that. How can I use ModelsIncluded or PropertiesIncluded? Thanks..

Comment: As far as I see: You can use the Export-SPBusinessDataCatalogModel cmdlet (as its name suggests) only for exporting models (it means you should use Get-SPBusinessDataCatalogMetadataObject -BdcObjectType Model, but not Catalog or LobSystem, for example), otherwise you receive an exception: "This command is only supported on Models". Forthermore, the Name parameter seems to be irrelevant when using Get-SPBusinessDataCatalogMetadataObject -BdcObjectType Catalog.

Answer (score 0):

Try change -BdcObjectType Model to  LobSystem

Comment: While this post may answer the question, we prefer more details such as "why". Please edit your post with additional details. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.